# node.js write modules for business logic (edge.js)

Tags: c#, node.js, edge.js

I fairly new to node.js and I don´t feel 100% comfortable writing business logic in node.js.

I have to support MSSQL as Database-Backend, so I came accross [Edge.js](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/). Subsequently I thought maybe it could be a good Idea writing my DataLayer and BusinessLogic as Edge.js modules.

Does anybody have experience with this approach?
Are there any limitations?

Comment: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver

Comment: yeah I know about node-sqlserver but this is only a Driver, with edge.js I could write the whole DbLayer and the BusinessLogic as Modules, but I´m not 100% sure if this is a good Idea?

Comment: Huh? You can write all of your logic in Node.js.

Comment: I know :) but I think .net especially C# has some advantages over javascript, when it comes to writing complicated BusinessLogic and MSSQL support (e.g. node-sqlserver does not support output params when executing StoredProcedures)! So I thought it would be really nice to do all this things in C# und just push the data to node, which is possible with edge.js! And the main reason why I want use node.js and not ASP.NET MVC is Stylus and Jade ;-) But I don´t know if this approach maybe has some disadvantages I overlooked...

Comment: The only disadvantage I can see is the maintenance of more interfaces.  However, I'd say the benefits (modularization and the fact that you know C# better) outweigh the negatives.

Comment: The maintenance of more Interfaces is something I can live with :-) I think I should give it a try!

Comment: At first I felt like I was doing something wrong with node.js talking to .net application using REST API. But when the data and business rules got complex I think I did a good choice. Will give edje.js a try though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edge.js (http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge) was created primarily to help Node.js developers in efficiently performing tasks that Node.js is not good at, for example:

- running CPU intensive operations (which Edge.js enables one to do on dedicated CLR threads),
- accessing functionality that is not available or not mature in Node.js (e.g. accessing MS SQL databases, which Edge.js enables you to do with ADO.NET),
- efficiently integrating pre-existing .NET components or business logic in new Node.js applications.

The primary cost of using Edge.js is in increased memory footprint, since your node.exe process is now hosting two virtual machines instead of one: V8 and CLR. However, that disadvantage becomes irrelevant if your alternative is to run .NET code in a separate process. Compared to the alternative of running .NET logic in an external process, Edge.js has the advantage of dramatically reduced latency (see http://bit.ly/1hQseHY), and simplicity (one process instead of two or more).